# PHP shell large output(100+ lines) to browser

Tags: php

I am trying to execute a shell script which will have 100+ lines and which is a dynamic data.
How can i print each line to the browser as shell executes.
Here is the way i am trying but it's not working?

```
<?php
    ob_start();  
    echo "<pre>";  
    system("/var/www/html/shell_script.sh -e <arg1>");  
    ob_flush();  
    flush();  
?>
```

but the below code is working , since i am looping...

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    for($i=0;$i<40;$i++)
    {
        echo 'printing...<br />';
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        ob_end_flush();
        usleep(300000);
    }
?>
```

Please advice me how to make my shell out put to the browser as it executes.

Comment: maybe try to update the page via AJAX (output data to file and make ajax requests every second...). I use exec() for such stuff... from PHP manual fpr flush() command: Server modules for Apache like mod_gzip may do buffering of their own that will cause flush() to not result in data being sent immediately to the client.

Comment: if it is the issue with mod_zip but how it is working with for loop?and also i tried with exec but nothing printing to browser. Can you please explain about AJAX? how can i make it to work?

Comment: run Your script in background: "/var/www/html/shell_script.sh -e <arg1> > output.txt" and with each ajax request open output.txt file and search for new lines...